# FeignClient Invalid HTTP error with WAR-deployed SpringBoot application

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-feign

I am observing a rather strange failure with netflix FeignClient communicating with a SpringBoot eureka client application WAR-deployed under tomcat.

My Setup:

1. Eureka Server running as a spring boot app .
2. SpringBoot App DEMO1 with @EnableDiscoveryClient deployed under tomcat as a WAR           file and running on `http://localhost:8080/DemoApp1-1.0.0/greeting`
3. SpringBoot App DEMO2 ( also a eureka client ), running as a spring boot app from gradle bootRun @ `http://localhost:9002`

Both apps are registered on the Eureka server and are accessible
DEMO2 has a feignclient pointing to a REST end point on DEMO1.

Though I can access the DEMO1 rest endpoint at `http://localhost:8080/DemoApp1-1.0.0/greeting` , the feignclient from the DEMO2 app fails with the following exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid HTTP executing GET http://localhost:8080/DemoApp1-1.0.0/greeting
    at feign.Client$Default.convertResponse(Client.java:157) ~[feign-core-8.16.0.jar:8.16.0]
    at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:74) ~[feign-core-8.16.0.jar:8.16.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.FeignLoadBalancer.execute(FeignLoadBalancer.java:77) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RC2.jar:1.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.FeignLoadBalancer.execute(FeignLoadBalancer.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RC2.jar:1.1.0.RC2]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient$1.call(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:109) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:303) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
...
```

Anyone has ideas on this?

Comment: Turns out this is due to tomcat 9 not setting a http response message . Tomcat 8 works as expected. So bottom line Tomcat9 and netflix-feign are incompatible. The feign.Client class expects a valid http response message in addition to the http status code. Will raise a bug for netflix feign.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved with feign 8.17.0